# What is the difference between a normal class and a data class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I tried to resolve task #6 (DataClass) at [Kotlin Koans](https://github.com/vicboma1/Kotlin-Koans#named-arguments). When I used the normal class in code, the test case failed.

Here's my code of the data class:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun task6(): List<Person> {
    return listOf(Person("Alice", 29), Person("Bob", 31))
}
```

Here's result of the data class:

```
[Person(name=Alice, age=29), Person(name=Bob, age=31)]
```

Here's my code of the normal class:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun task6(): List<Person> {
    return listOf(Person("Alice", 29), Person("Bob", 31))
}
```

Here's result of the normal class:

```
[i_introduction._6_Data_Classes.Person@4f47d241, i_introduction._6_Data_Classes.Person@4c3e4790]
```

Does that mean there is difference between a normal class and a data class in Kotlin. If yes, what is that?

***Updated***:

Thank @Mallow, you are right. That works:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Person(name=$name, age=$age)"
    }
}

fun task6(): List<Person> {
    return listOf(Person("Alice", 29), Person("Bob", 31))
}
```

Comment: There is a whole page about data classes in the documentation. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

for a data class.

> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all
>   properties declared in the primary constructor:
>
> equals()/hashCode() pair,
>
> toString() of the form "User(name=John, age=42)",
>
> componentN() functions corresponding to the properties in their order
>   of declaration,
>
> copy() function (see below).

see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: In my case that mean do not have to String in my class?

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm   to be precise, it have no "tostring method with a readable format", the default tostring just print class name and address,like "i_introduction._6_Data_Classes.Person@4f47d241"

Answer (score 38):

Most of the time we developers use class to keep only data in classes. Classes have some methods which needs to be overridden wrt the data it holds. ex: `hashCode()`, `equals()`.

Data classes automatically take care of such utilities.

From the official documentation:

> We frequently create a class to do nothing but hold data. In such a class some standard functionality is often mechanically derivable from the data. In Kotlin, this is called a data class and is marked as `data`.

> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all properties declared in the primary constructor:

> - equals()/hashCode() pair,
> - toString() of the form "User(name=John, age=42)",
> - componentN() functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration,
> - copy() function (see below).
>   If any of these functions is explicitly defined in the class body or inherited from the base types, it will not be generated.

To read more, check [data-classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

About the result, **Technically**, you are getting is different because of implementation of `toString()` method. data class' `toString()` method uses data class properties and values to form returning string. General class' `toString()` method uses hash code to form returning string.

Comment: i can assume `data class` as `struct` in c++?

Comment: @slier I wouldn't necessarily make that connection. With a struct, every property is inherently public, and there are not instance methods for structs.

Comment: @slier class and struct is functionally equivalent in C++. Just the public/private defaults are different. data class and class are also functionally equivalent in kotlin. Data classes just have more hidden methods and additional hidden constructors that help you code, log and debug easier with less boilerplate code.

Comment: Maybe struct in Golang?

Answer (score 16):

A `class` represents some data "type" and its behaviour(s) so from that point of view `data class` isn't any different than a `class`. But there are certain behaviours and rules about a `data class` that makes it a bit different:

1. Calling `toString()` on a data class dumps a string with all its member properties.
2. It has `componentN` method that `get` member properties by their order `n`.
3. It has a `copy` method which takes the member properties as parameters for making a diff copy of the object.
4. A `data class` can not be open. Cant be inherited.
5. It can not be `abstract`.
6. It can not be `nested`, `inner` or `sealed`.
7. Although it can inherit, define abstract methods and implement interfaces.
8. `data class` properties can be destructed into individual variables e.g `val (name, address) = Person("name", "address")`
9. `Pair(a, b)` internally uses `data class`.

Answer (score 11):

It is very common to create classes whose main goal is to hold data. If you want your class to be a convenient holder for your data you need to override the universal object methods:

- [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) - string representation
- [`equals()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/equals.html) - object equality
- [`hashCode()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/hash-code.html) - hash containers

Note: `equals()` is used for [structural equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#structural-equality) and it is often implemented among with `hashCode()`.

Usually, the implementation of these methods is straightforward, and your IDE can help you to generate them automatically. However, in Kotlin, you don't have to general all of these boilerplate code. If you add the modifier `data` to your class, the necessary methods are automatically added for you.

The return value of `toString()` will have the format `ClassName(parm1=value1, param2=value2, ...)`. `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods take into account all the properties declared in the primary constructor.

#### The `copy()` method

When you mark a class as a *data class*, the method `copy()` is also automatically generated which allows you to make copies of an existing instance. This feature is very handy when you are using your instances as keys for a `HashMap` or if you are dealing with multithreaded code.

Even though the properties of a data class are not required to be `val`, i.e., you can use `var`, it is strongly recommended that you use read-only properties, so that you make the instances immutable.

Finally, `componentN()` functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration are also generated by the compiler when you mark a class as a data class.

#### Sample Code

```kotlin
class PersonClass(val name: String, val age: Int)
data class PersonDataClass(val name: String, val age: Int)

>>> val ron = PersonClass("Ron", 18)
>>> val harry = PersonDataClass("Harry", 17)
>>> println(ron) // notice the string representation of a regular class
PersonClass@3b6eb2ec
>>> println(harry) // notice the string representation of a data class
PersonDataClass(name=Harry, age=17)
>>> val harryClone = harry.copy() // this creates a copy of the object referenced by harry
>>> val hermione = PersonDataClass("Hermine", 16)
>>> harry == harryClone
true
>>> harry == hermione
false
```

In summary, if you need a holder for data, you should use a data class which means adding the modifier `data` to your class. This will generate the following methods for you: `toString()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `componentN()`, and `copy()`, so you avoid writing boilerplate code. If you use a regular class, you won't have all these *"batteries included"*.

Comment: This is great to have a proper explanation of the thinking behind the concept rather than just a copy/paste of the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

`Data Class` contains internal code which we have to override in Java-like Kotlin generates the `equals(), hashCode(), and toString()`

**Kotlin:**

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: String)
```

**Java:**

```
class Student {
    public final String name;
    public final String age;

    public User(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public long hashCode() {
      
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return "User(name=" + name + ",age=" + age + ")";
    }
}
```

**Normal Class:**

1. Can be `abstract`, `open`, `sealed`, or `inner` but not for `Data Class`
2. Constructor parameter can be declared without var and val